How can I receive more information about a Direct Message in Instagram Graph API?
I'm trying to integrate the Direct Messages webhook for Instagram Graph API but I need more information about the Direct Message, more specifically about a Share.
For example, when someone sends a Share to the user, I receive this type of webhook:
"message": {
    "mid": "aWdfZAG1f....",
    "attachments": [{
        "type": "share",
        "payload": {
            "url": "https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/ig_messaging_cdn/...."
        }
    }]
}

The payload only has the image URL of the post, nothing else.
I need to know at least the user ID/username of the owner of that post (the user who posted it). Is there a way I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

How are you getting DM conversations/messages info from the instagram API? What are your GET-requests? I've searched high and wide but can't figure out the correct get request to get conversation ID from instagram, let alone anything from DMs. I got it working with a page token and ID, but then all I got was the facebook page's conversations, and not the instagram account's. (linked).
My situation: I'm trying to write a script that fetches the shared reel URLs from a certain conversation on my instagram account/creator page. But I can't figure out how to GET access to conversations or messages with my get requests. Either I get invalid endpoint or "nonexisting field" errors. How do you do it? (yes, I have all the permission)
Also, I was lead to believe from the insta documentation that you're supposed to use graph.instagram.com but the one that seem to work for instagram is the graph.facebook.com one. I would much appreciate to hear from you.

This is not an answer but another series of questions for OP, and also another entirely new question for SO. It should be a comment at best.
